# insert the array into the database

Tags: mysql, arrays, phpmyadmin

I am getting this result when I am using graph api . it is in array format

```
{
  "id": "216805086", 
  "name": "raj sharma", 
  "first_name": "raj ", 
  "last_name": "sharma", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/raj.sharma.5", 
  "username": "raj .sharma.5", 
  "favorite_teams": [
    {
      "id": "198358615428", 
      "name": "Mumbai Indians"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "190313434323691", 
      "name": "Indian Cricket Team"
    }
  ], 
  "favorite_athletes": [
    {
      "id": "100787839962234", 
      "name": "Saina Nehwal"
    }
  ], 
  "gender": "male", 
  "email": "raj.discoverme@gmail.com", 
  "timezone": 5.5, 
  "locale": "en_GB", 
  "verified": true, 
  "updated_time": "2013-08-13T06:01:17+0000"
}
```

I am working in a php language and phpmyadmin database . Now i want to insert the array into my database . Should i make a column for id , name , first_name ,last_name,link,favorite_teams  etc or should i make a one column for all of this ........
how toinsert tha array into the database

Comment: The answer is that you have to normalize the data and create your tables based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing facebook app data in a database is against Facebook policy http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

```
 $data = '{
  "id": "216805086", 
  "name": "raj sharma", 
  "first_name": "raj ", 
  "last_name": "sharma", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/raj.sharma.5", 
  "username": "raj .sharma.5", 
  "favorite_teams": [
    {
      "id": "198358615428", 
      "name": "Mumbai Indians"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "190313434323691", 
      "name": "Indian Cricket Team"
    }
  ], 
  "favorite_athletes": [
    {
      "id": "100787839962234", 
      "name": "Saina Nehwal"
    }
  ], 
  "gender": "male", 
  "email": "raj.discoverme@gmail.com", 
  "timezone": 5.5, 
  "locale": "en_GB", 
  "verified": true, 
  "updated_time": "2013-08-13T06:01:17+0000"
}';

//decode to get as php variable
$values = json_decode($data,true); //true to decode as a array not an object

$sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (id,name,first_name,last_name,link,username)
VALUES ('".$values['id']."','".$values['name']."','".$values['first_name']."','".$values['last_name']."','".$values['link']."','".$values['username']."')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Json_decode() takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

Comment: **-Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\fb.php on line 73
-Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\fb.php on line 73
-Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\fb.php on line 73
-Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\fb.php on line 73

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\fb.php on line 73**

Comment: if i use ur code , then i am getting this error and if remove 0 from $values[0]['name'] then data is inserting into the database but 1st column shows the curly brackets the and 2nd column shows the empty spaces and 3rd column is showing me the result

Comment: Sorry you can use key to access each data `$values['id']` OR use a loop to insert the array to database.

Comment: please can u explain me more ya u can edit ur answer to help me because i am new to this language

Comment: how to insert favorite_teams and favorite_athletes data into the  database

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not an array. This is [JSON](http://www.json.org/%E2%80%8E). In JSON there are two formats,

> JSONArray [ ]
>
> JSONObject { }

You are getting the JSONObject as your output. There is a function in PHP callerd [JSONDecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).
Go through this you will get idea.